# Different result in OCaml and ReasonML

Tags: list, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

There is a case mapping two vectors into a single vector. I expected that the result of both ML should be same. Unfortunately, the result of ReasonML is different. Please help and comment how to fix it.

**OCaml**

```
List.map2 (fun x y -> x+y) [1;2;3] [10;20;30];;
[11;;22;;33]
```

**ReasonML**

```
Js.log(List.map2 ( (fun (x,y) => x+y), [1,2,3], [10,20,30]))
[11,[22,[33,0]]]
```

Comment: My assumption that this is the same result, just reasonml represent a linked list in this way.

Answer (score 4):

This is the same result. If you run:

```
Js.log([11,22,33]);
```

You'll get:

```
[11,[22,[33,0]]]
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, How to print to console correctly?

Comment: It looks like you may want an array: `Js.log(Array.map2((x, y) => x + y, [|1, 2, 3|], [|10, 20, 30|]));` More info https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/list-and-array

Answer (score 4):

The result *is* the same, but you're using different methods of printing them. If instead of `Js.log` you use `rtop` or [sketch.sh](https://sketch.sh/), you'll get the output you expect:

```
- : list(int) = [11, 22, 33]
```

`Js.log` prints it differently because it is a BuckleScript binding to `console.log`, which will print the *JavaScript-representation* of the value you give to it. And lists don't exist in JavaScript, only arrays do.

The way BuckleScript represents lists is pretty much the same way it is done natively. A list in OCaml and Reason is a "cons-cell", which is essentially a tuple or a 2-element array, where the first item is the value of that cell and the last item is a pointer to the next cell. The `list` type is essentially defined like this:

```rust
type list('a) =
  | Node('a, list('a))
  | Empty;
```

And with this definition could have been constructed with:

```
Node(11, Node(22, Node(33, Empty)))
```

which is represented in JavaScript like this:

```
[11,[22,[33,0]]]
 ^   ^   ^  ^
 |   |   |  The Empty list
 |   |   Third value
 |   Second value
 First value
```

Lists are defined this way because immutability makes this representation very efficient. Because we can add or remove values without copying all the items of the old list into a new one. To add an item we only need to create one new "cons-cell". Using the JavaScript representation with imagined immutability:

```js
const old = [11,[22,[33,0]]];
const new = [99, old];
```

And to remove an item from the front we don't have to create anything. We can just get a reference to and re-use a sub-list, because we know it won't change.

```js
const old = [11,[22,[33,0]]];
const new = old[1];
```

The downside of lists is that adding and removing items *to the end* is relatively expensive. But in practice, if you structure your code in a functional way, using recursion, the list will be very natural to work with. And very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

@Igor Kapkov, thank you for your help. Base on your comment, I found a pipeline statement in the [link](https://reasonml.chat/t/js-log-list-output-for-lists-with-more-than-three-elements/975), there is a summary.

```
let a = List.map2 ( (fun (x,y) => x+y), [1,2,3], [10,20,30] )
let logl = l => l |> Array.of_list |> Js.log;
a |> logl


[11,22,33]
```